# What's the lightest way to automate .vue file compilation without webpack?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a web application that currently uses vuejs for part of its interface. The back-end is NOT in Node, so there is currently no package.json file or any tool from the typical npm stack in this repository.

We already have a bunch of non-npm dependencies that need to be installed in order to use the repository, so my coworkers aren't too open about the idea of adding another layer of complexity. I can't blame them for that, it's the reason why I use npm scripts and not even gulp in my other projects. I'm tired of spending hours learning and configuring build tools that never end up doing what I want anyway.

But since the `vue-cli` tool no longer includes the build command, I'm a bit stuck. Is there really no more CLI app to build vue files at all? And if so, what would be the smart way to use vue without webpack? Template strings are not maintainable at all, and `<script type="text/x-template">` don't work when you want to use multiple components from multiple files in the same page.

Comment: "since the vue-cli tool no longer includes the build command". source?

Comment: @EricGuan Well, from running the missing command. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/bin/vue-build

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question says 'without webpack' but you may be interested in [backpack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack) - a CLI app i came across for building Vue.js without requiring you to write any configuration code. It is basically webpack preconfigured as a minimalistic build system for Node.js. It provides two commands, `dev` for live reload enabled development and `build` for building you project.

Comment: From what I'm reading, backpack is mostly designed with back-end in mind (hence the name) and has pretty much nothing to do with vue... am I missing something?